# Running .reg files with wine

Tags: windows, wine

I am having trouble running `.reg` files with wine. I have tried a few solutions that other people have used but when I launch it return the following error:

```
There is no windows program configured to open this type of file.
```

I have tried the following:

- `wine regedit regkey.reg`
- Importy registry file in regedit
- `wine start regkey.reg`

The `.reg` file I am using works fine in my actual Windows system.

Comment: `wine regedit regkey.reg` should work...

Answer (score 8):

I managed to reimport exports done with [wine's `$> regedit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/regedit.1.html):

```
wine start regedit.exe /home/myname/path/foo.reg
```

**Note**: `foo.reg` coming from wine's regedit looks a little different than usual_:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SomeApplication\Layout]
"WindowState"="1"
"FormWidth"="800"
"FormHeight"="600"
"FormTop"="50"
"FormLeft"="50"
```

In constrast the (non-working) native form:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-123456789-1000\Software\SomeApplication\Layout]
"WindowState"="1"
```

The first version works reliably. But I am not sure, how to transform the latter to the former... (replacing line 1 is trivial, but according to what rules getting to those „simplified“ keys...)

Comment: great thanks, that worked for my wine on macOS like a charm

Comment: Worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the problem. It might have had something to do with the original solutions I posted. After I had done those I clicked on the .reg file and said "Open With Wine Registry Editor"

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I was not able to see, when right click on `.reg` file, "Open with wine Registry Editor"...maybe because of wine version. buy the way I found another way to run `.reg` files. 
 You need to open `regedit` from Playonlinux configuration options.

1. Open Playonlinux
2. Open "Configure"
3. Select the program from the list you need to apply the `.reg` file
4. Select Wine "window"
5. Registry Editor
6. Import `.reg` file

It worked for me but still I can not understand why I can not see "Open with wine registry editor" when right click on the `.reg` file.